# How to write a request with GROUPby and ORDERby in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have a grammar problem with Laravel.
I can not do an 'orderby' on nbr_point.
If anyone has an idea it will be great ...

```
$equipes = Equipes::with('rencontres')->with(['issues' => function($q){
     $q->selectRaw('equipe_id, sum(point_equipe) as nbr_point, 
         sum(case when point_equipe = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as victoire,  
         sum(case when point_equipe = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as match_null,  
         sum(case when point_equipe = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as defaite,
         max(journee) as last_day')
         ->join('rencontres', 'issues.rencontre_id','=','rencontres.id')
         ->groupby('equipe_id');
 }])
 ->where('ligue_id', '=', $id)
 ->get();

 $tabjournee = Tabjournees::where('ligue_id', '=', $id)->first();
 $rencontres = Rencontres::where('ligue_id', '=', $id)->get();

 return view('tabCrud', compact(
     'equipes',
     'ligues',
     'rencontres', 
     'tabjournee'
 ));
```

Comment: I'm not used to raw queries but I could help you with Eloquent if you wish?

Comment: Yes, I want you to explain to me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
$rencontres = Rencontres::where('ligue_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('journee', 'desc')->get();
```

Use `desc` or `asc` anyway you want the result.